# How to use variable defined inside setOnAction outside it?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have searched all over the internet for a solution to this but nothing seems to work.

What I want to do is use the variable "poeni" that is modified when a button is clicked and display that result in a label that is outside the OnActionEvent.

Here is the part of my code that is giving me trouble.

```
//The button
        Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
        rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                int poeni = 0; //The variable i want to use outside

                if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) poeni++;
                if(odgovor2_3.isSelected()) poeni++; //Theese if's check if the RadioButton is checked and increment if it is
                if(odgovor3_2.isSelected()) poeni++;
            }
        });


        //The label in which I want to display the results
        Label lbl_rezultat = new Label("Vas rezultat je: " + poeni);
```

Comment: This won't work, even if the variable was visible outside. The action handler will normally be called much later, when the even is being fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name says, **local** variables are *local* to the scope they are defined in.

So, when you want that an instance of some anonymous inner class has a mean to *communicate* with the enclosing class, you have to use a *field* on that outer class.

Like:

```
class Example {
  private int counter = 0;

  void someMethod() {
    Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
      rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) this.Example.poeni++;
...
```

But of course, that requires careful thinking how things should come together on that top level - as it might not necessarily be that *Example* class where you want your fields to be.

Long story short - local variables are local to their scope; you need *something* that exists in an enclosing scope in order to propagate such information to the outside of your local scope.

Comment: I would like to apologize for the very late reply, I had a lo of things to take care of and completely forgot to give feedback.
I just wanted to say that your answer helped me figure out the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are very welcome. In case you want to practice upvoting, now that you reached upvote privileges, feel free to do so... Next time you come by, I already hit the daily cap limit today :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a field of your class to use it in method and in scope of class. You can see this article [Scope of Variables In Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

```
class Rezultat{
    Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
    int poeni;//The scope of poeni starts form here
    rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            poeni = 0;

            if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) poeni++;
            if(odgovor2_3.isSelected()) poeni++; //Theese if's check if the RadioButton is checked and increment if it is
            if(odgovor3_2.isSelected()) poeni++;
        }
    });
    Label lbl_rezultat = new Label("Vas rezultat je: " + poeni);
  }//You can use variable to here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make that variable a class field.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int poeni;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
        rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                MyClass.this.poeni = 0;

                if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) MyClass.this.poeni++;
                if(odgovor2_3.isSelected()) MyClass.this.poeni++;
                if(odgovor3_2.isSelected()) MyClass.this.poeni++;
            }
        });


        //The label in which I want to display the results
        Label lbl_rezultat = new Label("Vas rezultat je: " + this.poeni);
    }
}
```

### Update:

This should be the correct way to do it the JavaFX style:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private final IntegerProperty poeni = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    public IntegerProperty poeniProperty()
    {
        return this.poeni;
    }
    public int getPoeni()
    {
        this.poeniProperty().get();
    }
    public void setPoeni(int value)
    {
        this.poeniProperty().set(value);
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
        rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                int count = 0;

                if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) count++;
                if(odgovor2_3.isSelected()) count++;
                if(odgovor3_2.isSelected()) count++;
                MyClass.this.setPoeni(count);
            }
        });


        //The label in which I want to display the results
        Label lbl_rezultat = new Label();
        lbl_rezultat.textProperty.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
            "Vas rezultat je: " + Integer.toString(MyClass.this.getPoeni()),
            MyClass.this.poeniProperty()));
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is very unlikely (at least) that `this.poeni` will be different from zero inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a mechanism so that the `label` is updated with the value of the variable. You can create a method and accept an `int` parameter. When `poeni` is updated you just need to invoke the method with the updated value. Inside the method you may update the `label`.

Another approach is to simply have the label defined above and marking it final. You can always set the text on label.

```
//The button
    Button rezultat = new Button("Pogledajte Vas rezultat");
    //The label in which I want to display the results
    final  Label lbl_rezultat = new Label();
    rezultat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int poeni = 0; //The variable i want to use outside

            if(odgovor1_1.isSelected()) poeni++;
            if(odgovor2_3.isSelected()) poeni++; //Theese if's check if the RadioButton is checked and increment if it is
            if(odgovor3_2.isSelected()) poeni++;
            lbl_rezultat.setText("Vas rezultat je: " + poeni);
        }
    });
```